# All shared_ptr refer to the same pointer in my vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, shared-ptr, make-shared

I created a vector of vector of `shared_ptr` class (`_cells`).

```
class Goban
{
  public:
    Goban();
    ~Goban();
  private:
    vector<vector<shared_ptr<Cell>>> _cells;
};
```

I initialize like that :

```
Goban::Goban() : _cells(18, vector<shared_ptr<Cell>>(18, make_shared<Cell>()))
{
}
```

The problem is all pointers refer to the same pointer dynamically (If I understood correctly).
So when I change an element in my class Cell using my vector, it changes all other elements.

Comment: Yep, that's what a shared_ptr does.

Comment: I want separate pointer, I should use unique_ptr ?

Comment: If you just want a managed list of cells, and aren't trying to do something specific with smart pointers, just use `vector<vector<Cell>>`. Vector manages its own memory.

Comment: To go a bit further on why it's behaving that way, The constructor you're using for `vector` _copies_ the argument you pass 18 times.`shared_ptr` increments a reference count each time it's copied, so that creates 18 references to the same cell.

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is all pointers refer to the same pointer dynamically

This is because you use the constructor of vector that makes N copies of the value argument. A copy of a shared pointer points to the shared object.

> I want separate pointer

Then don't use that constructor of vector. You can write a loop that calls `make_shared` to create each element, and a loop to repeat that for each vector.

Answer (score 2):

To get 18x18 distinct `shared_ptr`s, the correct way to initialize `_cells` might be:

```
Goban::Goban() : _cells(18, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Cell>>(18))) {
    for (auto& cs : _cells)
        for (auto& c : cs)
            c = std::make_shared<Cell>();
}
```

or

```
Goban::Goban() : _cells(18) {
    for (auto& cs : _cells) {
        cs.resize(18);
        for (auto& c : cs)
            c = std::make_shared<Cell>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just explicitly initialize your vector in the constructor body instead of the initializer list.

```
Goban::Goban()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 18; i++) {
        _cells.push_back(make_shared<Cell>());
    }
}
```